# I am going to South Korea and my passport is only valid for 5 more months, will I be rejected?

Tags: passports, paperwork, south-korea

I am going to South Korea and my passport is only valid for 5 more months, will I be rejected?

Answer (score 4):

Per [TIMATIC](https://cms.olympicair.com/timatic/webdocsI/spdbmainv.html), the database used by all airlines, regarding SOuth Korea:

> Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be
>     valid on **arrival**.

So South Korea does **not** require passports to be valid for 6 months, only during the visit.

In other words, you're good.

Comment: this link seems to be dead - can you provide a new link? I'm just a bit confused cause I'm seeing a number of differnt sources say different things and just want to make sure

Comment: @MrPizzzzzza All good TIMATIC interfaces have been clamped down sadly, so this is the least bad option https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/